# Find maximum values before a zero in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the formula `=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(T2:AC2>1,ROW(T2:AC2)),IF(T2:AC21>=1,ROW(T2:AC2))))`to find more than one maximum value before a zero from a range.

ROW has this values

`1​ 2​ 0​ 1​ 2​ 3​ 4​ 5​ 6​ 0`​

I want a formula/formulas that will return **2** and **6**

Thank you

Comment: With Office 365 you could use FILTER (shift the result range one to the left). With older versions you use a combination of INDEX/AGGREGATE.

Comment: If your data could look like: `1​ 2​ 0​ 1​ 2​ 3​ 4​ 6 5​ 0​` should the result still be `2` and `6`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad No, because `12` and `123456` are sequences of consecutive occurrences e.g LLXLLLLLLX

Comment: The example I gave answers exactly what you ask for (the maximum value before each `0`) tell us what the result should be with my example and what the logic is, exactly. Or provide more sample data and expected results.

Comment: Alright, lets take Soccer team X form for the last 10(ten) games is W W D W W W W W W L. Am trying to get how many times Team X has had consecutive wins(W). In this case, the first consecutive occurrence is 2 games before a draw(0). The second consecutive occurrence is 6 before a loss(0). So i need a formula that can pick 2 as a max for first occurrence and the same or another formula to pick 6 as a max for the second occurrence. Hope this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula

```
=LET(list,
   FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(A1:A16),"d","l"),"l","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
   LEN(list)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(list,"w","")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got this working:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(R:R,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(R$3:R$100)/((R$3:R$1100=0)*(R$2:R99<>0)),ROWS(S$3:S3))-1),"")`

Assuming the data is in column R, put the formula in column S. Link: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/find-more-than-one-maximum-value-before-a-zero.1188659/post-5793250.